# Retain username and password in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, passwords, retain

I have a webpage which contains username and password fields. In Android WebView, I loads that page and enter the user credentials to login. Now if the user logs out and logs in again, I want the previous username and password values to be retained in the fields of the WebView where we enter the credentials. I have seen some methods like `setHttpAuthUsernamePassword`,`savePassword` like this in WebView class of Android. I've tried with these methods to save the credentials and tried to get the values by this method `getHttpAuthUsernamePassword`. But it is not working. May I know how to do this using these methods or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution? I am facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 possibilities:

1. Save with JavaScript the login data with the `onClick` event in a cookie and restore them from the cookie if needed
2. Simply let the user decide if he want to store the login data (which is supported by the default android browser)

Answer (score 0):

When webview loads try to use this coding, I'm not sure on this, sorry for that.

```
Activity thisActivity;
thisActivity = this;
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(thisActivity);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this,

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(thisActivity);

CookieManager.getInstance();